# How was blood leaking from the ceiling?

Tags: plot-explanation, tess

In the Roman Polanski movie [*Tess* (1979)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080009/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), Tess killed her husband, Alec d'Urberville, off-screen, but his blood leaks from ceiling. She is clearly living in the royal house (see the designs of ceiling). How is blood still leaking from the ceiling?

[image]

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but any chance this is just imagination, if it doesn't make any sense directly?

Comment: It's not a  Royal house, just a large country house, if the film follows the plot of the novel. Alec has been stabbed and his blood is slowly seeping through the floorboards and the plaster.  This is the first sign of it coming through it is noticed and the body discovered.